# Как изменить цвет части текста в QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtimer, qtextedit, qtextcharformat

Я пишу тестер скорости набора текста с использованием *PyQt5*. 
Мне надо чтобы написанный текст подсвечивался красным или зеленым (зависит от корректности написания). 
Виджет  можно использовать любой.

```
import sys
import random

from PyQt5 import uic  # Импортируем uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QCheckBox, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from save_session import Save_session


class Game_form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('game_form.ui', self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.session = Save_session()
        with open("english_base1.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            self.english_base = f.readlines()
        with open("russian_base.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            self.russian_base = f.readlines()
        self.form_text_button.clicked.connect(self.form_text)

    def form_text(self):
        try:
            self.words_count = int(self.count_group.checkedButton().text())
            self.language = self.language_group.checkedButton().text()
            self.res = self.new_text()
            self.symbols = len(" ".join(self.res))
            self.text_field.setText(' '.join(self.res))
        except AttributeError:
            self.error_label.setText('Заполните поля')
            self.timer.start(3000)
            self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.error_label.setText(""))

    def new_text(self):
        self.text = []
        if self.language == 'Eng':
            for i in range(self.words_count):
                self.text.append(self.english_base[random.randint(0, 9924)].strip())
        else:
            for i in range(self.words_count):
                self.text.append(self.russian_base[random.randint(0, 10000)].strip())
        return self.text


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Game_form()
    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: покажите ваш код, в котором вы хотите подсвечивать текст.

Comment: докинул в описание вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что вы задумали, может выглядеть примерно так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text_for_typing = QTextEdit(self)
        self.text_for_typing.setEnabled(False)
        self.text_for_typing.setGeometry(0, 53, 810, 344)
        self.text_for_typing.setStyleSheet("""
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
            font: 17pt Arial Rounded MT Bold;
        """)

        self.wpm = QLabel("<center>0 WPM</center>", self)
        self.wpm.setGeometry(0, 0, 267, 47)
        self.wpm.setStyleSheet("""
            font: 28pt Arial Rounded MT Bold;
            color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        """)

        self.secs = QLabel("<center>0 Sec</center>", self)
        self.secs.setGeometry(273, 0, 265, 47)
        self.secs.setStyleSheet("""
            font: 28pt Arial Rounded MT Bold;
            color: rgb(0,85,0);
        """)

        self.accuracy = QLabel("<center>0 %</center>", self)
        self.accuracy.setGeometry(542, 0, 267, 47)
        self.accuracy.setStyleSheet("""
            font: 28pt Arial Rounded MT Bold;
            color: rgb(0, 85, 127);
        """)
        
        self.area_for_typing = QTextEdit(self)
        self.area_for_typing.setGeometry(0, 403, 810, 450)
        self.area_for_typing.setStyleSheet("""
            color: rgb(170, 170, 127);
            font: 16pt Arial Rounded MT Bold;
        """)
        self.area_for_typing.document().contentsChange.connect(self.contents_change)
        
        self.format = QTextCharFormat()
        self.format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 22, QFont.Bold))

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        """)

        self.generate_symbols()
       
        self.timer = QTimer()                 
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.start)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 4, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawLine(0, 50, 820, 50)
        painter.drawLine(270, 50, 270, 0)
        painter.drawLine(540, 50, 540, 0)
        painter.drawLine(0, 400, 820, 400)

    def contents_change(self, position, charsRemoved, charsAdded):
        if not self.area_for_typing.document().toPlainText():
            return
        if len(self.area_for_typing.document().toPlainText()) == 1:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.current_wpm = 0
            self.accuracy_per = 0
            self.timer.start(1000)

        cursor = self.text_for_typing.textCursor()
        cursor.setPosition(position)
        end = cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter, 1)
        self.text = self.text_for_typing.toPlainText()

        try:
            if end:
                letter_text = self.text[position]
                letter_area_for_typing = self.area_for_typing.document().toPlainText()[position]
                if letter_text == letter_area_for_typing:
                    self.format.setTextOutline(QPen(QColor("green")))
                else:
                    self.format.setTextOutline(QPen(QColor("red")))
        except:
            pass
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(self.format)

    def generate_symbols(self):
        text_for_typing = ""
        strings = []
        file = open("ENRUS.txt", encoding = "utf-8")
        file.seek(0)

        for line in file:
            strings.append(line[:-1])
        for i in range(20):
            random_int = random.randint(0, 20)
            word = strings[random_int]
            text_for_typing += word + " "

        text_for_typing = text_for_typing[0].swapcase() + text_for_typing[1:]
        self.text_for_typing.setText(f"<center>{text_for_typing}</center>")

    def start(self):
        if self.area_for_typing.toPlainText() != "":
            try:
                text_for_typing = self.text_for_typing.toPlainText()
                area_text = self.area_for_typing.toPlainText()
                correct_letters = 0
                allow = False

                for i in range(0, len(area_text)):
                    if area_text != "":
                        if text_for_typing[i] == area_text[i]:
                            correct_letters += 1
                            
                if len(text_for_typing)-1 <= len(area_text):
                    allow = True
                    self.stop()
                    return

                if allow == False:
                    self.seconds += 1

                if self.seconds > 0 and correct_letters > 0:
                    self.accuracy_per = round(
                        ( correct_letters / len(area_text) ) * 100)
                    self.current_wpm = round(
                        ((correct_letters/self.seconds) * 60) / 7.2) 

                self.secs.setText(f"<center>{self.seconds} Sec</center>")
                self.wpm.setText(f"<center>{self.current_wpm} WPM</center>")
                self.accuracy.setText(f"<center>{self.accuracy_per} %</center>")
            except:
                self.stop()
                
    def stop(self):
        msg = QMessageBox.information(
            None, 
            'Стоп', 
            'Смотрим результат.'
        ) 
        self.text_for_typing.clear()
        self.area_for_typing.clear()
                
        self.generate_symbols()
                
        self.wpm.setText("<center>0 WPM</center>")
        self.secs.setText("<center>0 Sec</center>")
        self.accuracy.setText("<center>0 %</center>")
        self.timer.stop()     


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("TypingSpeed")
    w.setWindowIcon(QIcon("im.png"))
    w.resize(820, 640)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ENRUS.txt**

```
я пишу тестер
скорости 
набора текста
с использованием 
PyQt5.
Мне надо чтобы написанный текст
подсвечивался 
красным
или
зеленым
(зависит от корректности написания).
I am writing a typing 
speed 
tester using
PyQt5. 
I need the written text to 
be highlighted 
in red 
or green 
(depending on the correct spelling). 
777
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое, работает

Comment: @Kirill пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour